# Load gridview using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am looking for a solution to load my gridview using ajax
situation is like this below,
gridview is populated with already existing files in a folder and when a user upload another file that file also need to populate on the gridview using ajax.
I am using asp.net c# jquery
Gridview contains 3 columns one for filename ie,boundfiled and 2 other template field for download and delete.
How can i done please help me.

```
<div id="dvListFiles">
  <wuc:EmptyGridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowEmptyTable="False">
      <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="File Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text = "Download" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" OnClick = "DownloadFile"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID = "lnkDelete" Text = "Delete" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat = "server" OnClick = "DeleteFile" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
  </wuc:EmptyGridView>
```

c# code

```
string path =Configuration.DocumentationFileUploadLocation;
       if (Session["CaseNumber"] != "")
           path = path + "/" + Session["CaseNumber"];
       else
       {
           path = path + "/" + HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
       }

       if (Directory.Exists(path))
       {
           string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(path);
           List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
           foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
           {
               files.Add(new ListItem(Path.GetFileName(filePath), filePath));
           }
           GridView1.DataSource = files;
           GridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

Thanks
Alex

Comment: What are you using to do the file upload?

Comment: I have a java script method for file uploading...and i have a method for displaying some messages while file upload is done...in that point i am trying to call ajax method to load grid-view with newly uploaded file.